# Basic authentication for my app - Node JS & Mongo as backend and Angular as front end

Tags: node.js, basic-authentication

I've decided I need to take on some new challenges and so decided I want to learn to build an app using mongo db, node js, and angular.

I have a little knowledge on NodeJS, but I am totally new to AngularJS and NodeJs authentication.
I am creating a simple blogging app in AngularJS as the front end and NodeJs-MongoDB combo as backend, where in users can

1. create account
2. login to existing account
3. write some new blog (can mark it as private)
4. view his previous blogs
5. view others blog (which weren't marked private)

Need some help on how to have a basic level authentication for user login at the backend side and how to maintain cookies and sessions.

Comment: http://passportjs.org/guide/

Answer (score 0):

Make life easy.  Express & Stormpath.  You should have full auth up in a few minutes.

https://docs.stormpath.com/nodejs/express/

Comment: This might also helpful too.  https://stormpath.com/blog/build-nodejs-express-stormpath-app/